# Is there a way that i store timestamp with time zone in Postgres and not converting it to UTC

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, timestamp, timezone

I want to save in Postgres `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column

> `2012-08-24 14:00:00+03:00`

After a `SELECT` I am getting:

> `2012-08-24 11:00:00+00:00`

I know that my DB is on UTC zone, but is there a way to save it and not lose original timezone info that I sent?

Comment: Not if you are using `timestamptz` type. If you want to do this then you need to use the `timestamp` type for the timestamp value and a separate column for the offset/timezone .

Comment: That is my alternative, but there's no way to do this without a separate column ? @AdrianKlaver

Comment: No. `timestamptz` does not store the time zone it just rotates the timestamp to a UTC value for storage. It then rotates the value from UTC to whatever is the controlling `timezone` value is  at the time. See *8.5.1.3. Time Stamps* here [Datetime Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) for more information.

Comment: You *can* and should use `timestamptz` if your source data comes with timezone offsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No [date/time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) type stores time zone because it's a separate piece of information. [Do not use plain `timestamp`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timestamp_.28without_time_zone.29) if your source data comes with timezone offsets because it'll be trimmed off - the `timestamptz` is just as light, just as flexible, and it doesn't truncate the offset. If you wish to retain the source offset/timezone, you need to save it to a separate column - timestamp is meant to store a *when* not a *where* - the latter is only used to clarify the former.

If offset or other valid time zone info is present in the value literal/constant, it's used to shift the timestamp to UTC for internal storage. When the db reads it back to you when you `select`, it's shifted once again according to your [`timezone` setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE): [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6UeKFA6y)

```
create table test(tstz timestamptz, ts timestamp);
insert into test 
select '2012-08-24 14:00:00+03:00'::timestamptz,
       '2012-08-24 14:00:00+03:00'::timestamp
returning *;
```

| tstz | ts |
| --- | --- |
| 2012-08-24 11:00:00+00 | 2012-08-24 14:00:00 |

The offset you see by default when you select a `timestamptz` is your current timezone: it basically means *this timestamp, as observed in a timezone with this offset*. Note that unless you add the minutes `:00`, it's trimmed off as insignificant both in default output and in [`to_char()` formatting function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html). If you really want to get the output you specified, for a reason only known to you, by all means you can - simply set the setting accordingly:

```
set timezone='utc-03:00';
select tstz,ts from test;
```

| tstz | ts |
| --- | --- |
| 2012-08-24 14:00:00+03 | 2012-08-24 14:00:00 |

```sql
select to_char(tstz,'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MI-SSAMOF'),
       to_char(ts,'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MI-SSAMOF') from test;
```

| to_char | to_char |
| --- | --- |
| 2012-08-24 02-00-00PM+03 | 2012-08-24 02-00-00PM+00 |

```
--Standard time: Australian Central Western Standard Time (ACWST)
--Example city: Eucla
set timezone='UTC +8:45';
select tstz,ts from test;
```

| tstz | ts |
| --- | --- |
| 2012-08-24 02:15:00-08:45 | 2012-08-24 14:00:00 |

```sql
select to_char(tstz,'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MI-SSAMOF'),
       to_char(ts,'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MI-SSAMOF') from test;
```

| to_char | to_char |
| --- | --- |
| 2012-08-24 02-15-00AM-08:45 | 2012-08-24 02-00-00PM+00 |

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

Postgres adjusts all `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` inputs to UTC, an offset of zero. Retrieved values remain in UTC, an offset of zero.

If you need the original offset, record that info in another column.

### Postgres adjusts to UTC (offset of zero)

> timestamp with timezone column'2012-08-24 14:00:00+03:00' and after trying to do a select i'm getting '2012-08-24 11:00:00+00

As you have seen, and as [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), for a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, Postgres uses the input’s offset-from-UTC to adjust to an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Your offset indicates a time of 14:00 with an offset of 3 hours ahead of UTC. So Postgres adjusts the time to 11:00 with an offset of zero. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different perspective.

#### Beware of tooling with auto-adjust anti-feature

Postgres retrieves the stored value with its offset of zero.

Unfortunately, many tools choose to dynamically apply some default time zone onto the retrieved value. While well-intentioned, this anti-feature confuses the picture, creates an illusion that the moment was stored with a particular time zone or offset. But, no, in Postgres values in a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` are *always* stored in UTC (offset of zero), and *always* retrieved in UTC (offset of zero).

#### Behavior varies across database engines

The SQL standard barely addresses date-time issues. So much of date-time handling behavior in various databases is implementation-specific.

Some other database engines do the same as Postgres, auto-adjusting to an offset of zero. But some database engines may not. Always study the doc.

### Store offset in another column

If knowing the original offset is important to you, you’ll need to save that fact as a value in another column. I would suggest a column of a textual type, storing offset values in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.